# Stop Explorer process freeze PowerShell window

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell file (Script A). It open another PS script (new window - Script B) where is a code for silent install application and other stuff.
During that installation process windows explorer is auto closed. After that Script B is doing other stuff, and then finishing without error, and exit.

Only Script A is then open where is few command left and on final should be exit. But it won't. Just freezes.

Is any of you faced situation like that?
When Explorer will be not closed then everything works fine and script A exits fine.

Basically it looks like this:

Script A:

```
...
Start-Process PowerShell -wait $PathToScriptB -WindowStyle Minimized
...
Exit
```

Script B:

```
...
Start-Process $SetupFile -wait
...
Exit
```

Comment: What happens if you do not use Start-Process to run script B from script A, but instead dot-source it (so it runs in the current scope as script A)

Comment: In fact its running and ending fine. Any idea why Start-Process don't work's here? And second question about that - is in "dot-source" can be used variable? I tried to run like that: .\$PathToScriptB, but then got error msg: ".\$PathToScriptB: The term '.\$PathToScriptB' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program...".

Comment: Just do `. $PathToScriptB` if that variable contains the full path and filename of your script B. With dot-sourcing, the secondary script runs in the same scope so functions and variables are visible in script A. You can remove `exit` in script B.